# Build's artifact doesn't download

Tags: azure-devops

In my build, I publish an artifact which I can see successfully published to DevOps. However, when I download it using the "Download Build Artifacts" task, the log says:

"Linked artifacts count:  0

Successfully downloaded artifacts to F:\agent_work\2\a"

And no file is downloaded. What am I missing? My publish and download tasks are attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Build's artifact doesn't download

You may have misunderstood these two task [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) and [Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops).

`Publish Build Artifacts` task is used to publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines, TFS, or a file share.

`Download Build Artifacts` task is used to download build artifacts to the agent.

So, if you use `Download Build Artifacts` task to download the build artifacts, it will be saved on the agent, that the reason why you can not see any file is downloaded.

To download the build artifacts, we could use [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and Publish Build Artifacts task, like:

[image]

and

[image]

When the build finished, we could get the file from Summary tab:

[image]

Hope this helps.